# My maven-cucumber-selenium-junit-allure project doesn't generate allure-results

Tags: maven, allure

I created an automated-test project you can see below my maven pom.xml.
If I run `mvn clean test` command, allure-results aren't generated but test cases run.
I read through allure documentation and looked for the solution but it doesn't work for me.

What could be the problem?

Here is my **pom.xml** content:

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>org.prozenda</groupId>
 <artifactId>TravelLedgerCucumber</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <properties>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
     <allure.version>2.18.1</allure.version>
     <maven.allure.version>2.11.2</maven.allure.version>
     <aspectj.version>1.8.4</aspectj.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
         <version>7.4.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.13.2</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
         <artifactId>allure-cucumber4-jvm</artifactId>
         <version>${allure.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
         <version>7.4.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
         <version>7.4.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
         <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
         <version>4.2.2</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
         <artifactId>allure-cucumber4-jvm</artifactId>
         <version>2.18.1</version>
     </dependency>

 </dependencies>

 <build>
     <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.3.0</version>
             <configuration>
                 <descriptorRefs>
                     <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                 </descriptorRefs>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.20</version>
             <configuration>
                 <argLine>
                     -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                     -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm"
                 </argLine>
                 <systemProperties>
                     <property>
                         <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                         <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                     </property>
                 </systemProperties>
             </configuration>
             <dependencies>
                 <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                     <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                     <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                 </dependency>
             </dependencies>
         </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>

</project>```
````

Answer (score 0):

The `project.build.directory` is a temporal directory what is generated when you build the project. Don't use that folder to store your results. Creates a folder in the root project and put the allure results in that dir.